# Is it possible to create lists or other mutable objects in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

It would be very useful for my current task to have lists or sets in Crystal Reports. Unfortunately I haven't found anything in my documentation or online search. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle mutable list in an external function. You can create UFL and expose functions like ListCreate, ListAdd, ListRead, ListDispose

If you don't want to deal with UFLs you can resize the array using redim preserve

redim preserve arrayname[new size];

Obviously this will copy the existing array into a new one and increase/decrease the size so there will be performance penalty. However, Crystal reports is slow anyway and I doubt copying a small array will be a significant performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to answer because the actual use is not stated. 
In any case, you can declare and populate array variables in Crystal formulas.
And you can set the scope of these variables so they maintain their values globally.

Comment: I want to make a global list and not a global array. It has to be mutable ...